# '...' is not defined (w117) что это?

Tags: javascript, jshint

Доброго времени суток :)
Я изучаю js, установил *jshint* в *vs code*.
Проблема вот в чем:
при использовании `console.log` или `alert` и прочего подобного, того же `prompt`, например, в консоли *jshint* выдает мне *problem*'сы так сказать, типа `'prompt' is not defined. (W117)", 'console' is not defined. (W117)`. Как убрать это? Будто бы он он думает что я объекты пытаюсь указать или что, как это понимать? Просто напрягают эти восклицательные знаки, хотя всё работает.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти переменные определены не в самом JS, а только в некоторых средах исполнения, например, в браузере. Вам нужно в настройках jshint указать окружение. См. опции `browser` и `devel` в https://jshint.com/docs/options/#environments

Comment: Я понял, спасибо!